# Session variable value changes during page redirect. - Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a login page for a tracker. I have verified the username and password by validating the same against the DB.

When the validation is successful, I have just set the session variable with username as it is required throughout the session. But the session variable changes when it is redirected to the next page.

When retrieving the username in the next page, the session variable has been changed. The code is pasted below. Please help.

Code in Login page:

```
if (isValidUser)
{
Session["LoginUserName"] = Name;
Response.Redirect("xxx.aspx",false);
}
```

Code in xxx.aspx:

```
User= Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();
```

//Getting different value while retrieving User from session.

Comment: Changed to what, specifically?  Is there anything else anywhere in the code which writes to that session variable?  I suspect there's more going on here than what's presented in the question.

Comment: Change `LoginUserName` in both lines of code to `MrBobby`. Does it then work (i.e. is the value what you expect)?

Comment: Consider putting a breakpoint everywhere you set `Session["LoginUserName"]`.  I suspect you will find another line that is changing it.  Review Peter B's answer

Answer (score 2):

If you specify **`endResponse: false`**, then processing of the page & any events continues despite the Redirect which was added to the output stream. This could well change the `Session`.

Try calling Redirect without the `endResponse: false` parameter:

```
Response.Redirect("xxx.aspx");
```

If you specify **`endResponse: true`** or if you leave it out entirely, then processing of the page is silently aborted after the Redirect with a harmless `ThreadAbortException`. AFAIK this is the normal way of doing a Redirect, and you need to have good reasons to NOT abort after a Redirect, also you need to take great care through all your remaining code because page processing continues.